# 'Execute Command' keyword does not complete the execution on remote machine

Tags: python-2.7, ssh, robotframework

I am trying to run a command (Jar file execution) on a remote machine using the 'Execute Command' keyword of SSH library. But the control returns even before the command execution is completed. Is there a way to wait until the command is executed?

Below are the keywords written:

`Run The Job
    [Arguments]    ${machine_ip}  ${username}  ${password}  ${file_location}  ${KE_ID}
    Open Connection     ${machine_ip}   timeout=60
    Login    ${username}  ${password}
    ${run_jar_file}=     Set Variable    java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=dev ${file_location} Ids=${KE_ID}
    ${output}=    Execute Command    ${run_jar_file}
    Log    ${output}
    Sleep    30
    Close Connection`

Answer (score 0):

Use Read and Write, instead of using "Execute Command" so that you can specify timeout for command execution.

refer: http://robotframework.org/SSHLibrary/latest/SSHLibrary.html#Write

Comment: The 'Write' Keyword does not have a timeout. The keyword 'Write Until Expected Output' has it. But this is not what I need. I want to run it just once and wait until execution completes. The output here will be a log trace.

Comment: While importing SSHLibrary pass argument as timeout. "Library   SSHLibrary     10 seconds"

Answer (score 0):

You are explicitly asking for the command to be run in the background (by virtue of adding `&` as the last character in the command to be run), so the ssh library has no way of knowing when the program you're running exits. If you want to wait for it to finish, don't run it in the background.

In other words, remove the trailing `&` from the command you are running.

Comment: I did try without '&' first. But the execution would not complete. So I added it to check if it would run in background even if the connection with machine was closed.

Comment: @DeeptiK: you can't have it both ways -- you can't run it in the background _and_ wait for it to complete.

Comment: I have edited the code. I have run it without 'nohup' and '&' . I see the logs now. But not the complete one. Hence indicating that the execution did not complete. And connection was closed even before completion.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still strugling with this one, i have discovered solution

```
Open Connection    ${SSH_HOST}    timeout=10s
Login    login    pass
Write    your_command
Set Client Configuration    prompt=$    
${output}=    Read Until Prompt 
Should End With     ${output}    ~ $
```